# What Ubuntu 20.04 package gives the Perl module Locale::Language?

Tags: package-management, 20.04, perl

What Ubuntu 20.04 package gives the Perl module Locale::Language?  I've looked on https://packages.ubuntu.com/ but I can't find anything.  Web search isn't turning up anything.  Not sure I'm searching right.

Answer (score 1):

Locale::Language is deprecated, suggest you install

```
sudo apt-get install liblocale-codes-perl
```

See below that reproduces the warning and suggestion to use  the separate liblocale-codes-perl package, as Locale::Language is deprecated

see:

```
$ perl -e 'use Locale::Language'
Locale::Codes will be removed from the Perl core distribution in the next major release. Please install the separate liblocale-codes-perl package. It is being used at 
/usr/share/perl/5.28/Locale/Language.pm, line 22.
```

If you don't have Locale::Language installed you may get a different error

```
$ perl -e 'use Locale::Language'
Can't locate Locale/Language.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Locale::Language module) ...
```

You can use the cpan program to install it

```
cpan Locale::Language
```

but since it is deprecated suggest you install

```
sudo apt-get install liblocale-codes-perl
```

Answer (score 0):

To find which package provide the perl module, use:

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search <Perl::Module> | awk '{print $1}' | uniq | tr -d \:
```

e,g, in your case:

```
 apt-file search Locale::Language | awk '{print $1}' | uniq | tr -d \:
```

sample output:

```
liblocale-codes-perl
```

Then install it:

```
sudo apt install liblocale-codes-perl
```